# Open New SwiftUI Window from AppKit NSButton

Tags: swiftui, appkit

I want to show a SwiftUI view in a new window popup from within an AppKit app. I'm currently doing this in a storyboard by doing a `Show` segue from an `NSButton` to an `NSViewController`.

[image]

I'm trying to do this in code like this:

```
@IBAction func clickTest(_ sender: NSButton) {
  let prefsView = NSHostingController(rootView: PreferencesView())
  self.presentAsModalWindow(prefsView) //I don't know how to do a regular "Show"
}
```

When I click the button, I know a modal is appearing, but it's invisible. I know it's there because I hear the `NSBeep` sound when I try to click back on my main app window. I can also see the `Untitled` window in the Window menu.

Here is `PreferencesView()`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PreferencesView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
  }
}

struct PreferencesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    PreferencesView()
  }
}
```

Is there something else I need to do to make a window appear with my SwiftUI view in it?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. It takes a little help from AppKit. You have to create a new `NSWindowController` and use that to house your SwiftUI view (`NSHostingController`):

```
@IBAction func clickTest(_ sender: NSButton) {
  //SwiftUI wrapper
  let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: PreferencesView())

  //New window holding our SwiftUI view
  let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
  window.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 380, height: 400))
  
  //Create a new window controller and show the window   
  let controller = NSWindowController(window: window)
  controller.showWindow(nil)
}
```

If anyone knows of a better way, I'm all ears. : )

Answer (score 0):

With modern AppKit API you can use code like this:

```
@IBAction func clickTest(_ sender: NSButton) {

    let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: MySwiftUIView())
    hostingController.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 380, height: 400)
    hostingController.sizingOptions = .preferredContentSize
   
    presentAsModalWindow(hostingController)
}
```

or you can present the SwiftUI view as a modal sheet with:

```
    presentAsSheet(hostingController)
```